# How to upload files using multer in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

I want to upload images using multer. But it is not working. What is wrong here?

This code is in my route file.

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'public/uploads/' });
```

And this is my post route.

```
router.post('/addNewFood', upload.single('avatar'),function (req, res, next) {
console.log(req.files);
});
```

Comment: http://lollyrock.com/articles/express4-file-upload/

Comment: any specific error  ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for me. Used express and node.

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('avatar');

router.post('/addNewFood', //Your authentication check,// 
  function (req, res, next) {

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect(req.headers.referer + "/error.html");
            return;
        }

        if (!req.files) {
            res.redirect(req.headers.referer + "/error.html");
            return;
        } else {
            //Implement your own logic if needed. Like moving the file, renaming the file, etc.
            res.redirect(req.headers.referer);
        }
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Great example for including authentication... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install the package

> npm install --save multer

You can try the following way, 
In the server side, In your routes or controller file configure the multer:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/images/uploads')   
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)      
    }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

In the storage object, 
    destination is stand for, where the file will be uploaded. So make sure in your project directory, /public/images/uploads path is created. Otherwise you may want to change the file path.

Also in storage object filename is stands for, what will be the uploaded file name. Here I add the current time with the original file name to make the all file name unique.

Now in your desired routing, suppose

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    //here your other task.
});
```

Now your file is uploaded. Make sure the client side is using the same name, In this case 'image'.

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" class='form-control'>
```

This is a single file upload procedure. 
For multiple files

```
router.post('/', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  //your task goes here
});
```

For more information, check this [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Answer (score 0):

> 

```js
    const multer = require("multer");
 
function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/jpg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
    cb(new Error('I don\'t have a clue!'))
}



var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
    }
})

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage, limits: {
        fieldSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
        fileFilter: fileFilter
    }
})

 router.post("/", upload.single("image_url"),(req, res) => {
  const new User=new User({
  image_url: req.file.path
 })
```